# If I have thousands of distinct tickers how do I keep only 101 tickers?

Tags: stata

I built a Stata dataset with more than 24 million observations. Most of these observations are daily stock market prices for companies in North America. I have also created one variable called `issuance` which equals 0 when the company hasn't issued a green bond during that specific day and 1 when the company issues a green bond. I have about 101 distinct companies that issued green bonds at some point and out of the thousands of the companies that I have in my dataset, I only want to keep every line for the companies that have issued the green bond only. How do I do that?

I tried to think about a way to create another variable `x` where it will take 1 as a value on each line if the company has issued a green bond at some point and 0 if it hasn't. Then it would be easy to keep all the companies that have issued a green bond at some point by entering `keep if x==1` but again the only way to do this is to go over all 101 distinct companies manually and I don't think that's very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like

```
egen tokeep = max(issuance), by(company)
keep if tokeep
```

See https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/create-variable-recording/ for discussion.